# Dart create and transform an SVG path

Tags: svg, dart, dart-html

I recently started programming in Dart (www.dartlang.org).
Now I try to display an SVG path and scale the path to fit in a div of 20px * 20px;

I do have a path, and I did create a transformation matrix, but how does one apply the matrix to the path?

My code so far:

```
    // create an svg element
    SvgSvgElement svg = new SvgSvgElement();
    // create a path
    PathElement path = new PathElement();
    // draw something
    path.setAttribute('d', myPath);
    // add the path to the svg
    svg.append(path);
    // add the svg to a table cell allready in the DOM
    myDiv.append(svg);

    // start scaling
    // get bounding box
    Rect bb = path.getBBox();
    num xx = bb.width ==0 ? 1 : 20/bb.width;
    num yy = bb.height==0 ? 1 : 20/bb.height;
    num mm = min(xx, yy);

    // create svg transformation matrix to scale the image
    // |  x-prev  |   |a c e||  x-new  |   | ax-new + cy-new + e |
    // |  y-prev  | = |b d f||  y-new  | = | bx-new + dy-new + f |
    // |  z-prev  |   |0 0 1||    1    |   |         1           |
    Matrix matrix = svg.createSvgMatrix();
    matrix.a = mm; // xx
    matrix.b = 0;
    matrix.c = 0;
    matrix.d = mm; // yy
    matrix.e = -(bb.x * mm); // dx
    matrix.f = -(bb.y * mm); // dy

    // do something here to apply the transformation....
```

**--EDIT--**

*I've now read parts of the MDN after reading Carlo's reply. The SVG specs are much more complicated than I was anticipating. I got one step further though.*

I now try to apply the transformation matrix to the svg like so:

```
    var a = svg.createSvgTransformFromMatrix(matrix);
    print('a: ' + a.toString());
```

but this does not apply the transformation as I would expect.

The print statement prints
***a: instance of 'Transform'***
, so I suspect I still have to apply this transformation somehow?

**--END EDIT--**

And now I'm lost.

How would I apply the transformation?
I could not find any examples and the Dart API reference does not give me enough details to figure it out.

Kind regards,
Hendrik Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it's a different language, the classes implement the interfaces defined by [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/) (if you watch closely you can see that the first paragraph of many Dart documentation pages is taken from MDN). So, to apply the matrix you have to create a [`SVGTransform`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#InterfaceSVGTransform) instance representing that transformation. To get it, look at the [`transform`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGTransformable__transform) property: it's an animated value, so you'll need to get its [`baseVal`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#__svg__SVGAnimatedTransformList__baseVal) which is a list of transformations (currently empty). Now on this object you have to call the [`createSvgTransformFromMatrix`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#__svg__SVGTransformList__createSVGTransformFromMatrix) method and append the object returned to the transformation list.

In code should be something like this:

```
TransformList pathTransformList = path.transform.baseVal;
pathTransformList.appendItem(pathTransformList.createSvgTransformFromMatrix(matrix));
```

Since Dart implementation of `TransformList` is also a `List`, I think you could also use its [`add`](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_svg/TransformList.html#add) method. Give a look at [`initialize`](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_svg/TransformList.html#initialize) too.

Comment: Hi Carlo. Thanks for your help so far. I can now create an SVGTransform, but am unsure how to apply the transform to the svg. Any suggestions? See my edited question.

Comment: You can apply it by adding the transform to the `TransformList` object using the method `appendItem`. Try something like `path.transform.baseVal.appendItem(a)`.