# Dart SVG Translate an object

Tags: dart, dart-html

I'm trying to translate an ellipse in SVG with Dart. I haven't found any explanation on how to do that, other than the SetAttribute way

```dart
ellipse.setAttribute('transform', 'translate($acx, $acy)');
```

I have found that the EllipseElement has a notation like this:

```dart
ellipse.transform.baseVal[...].setTranslate(acx,acy);
```

..but it doesn't work. I'm totally not sure how setTranslate works and I suppose I have to tell which element to translate but I have no idea how.
Is it better to use setATtribute instead of trying to use the other method?

Comment: I seem to have some misunderstanding problems, since I fail to understand also ellipse.style.setColor use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully tried

```dart
ellipse.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(150, 150)');
```

if you create the `transform` attribute using `setAttribute` then the following is working too

```dart
ellipse.transform.baseVal.first.setTranslate(20, 100);
```

or you can add a `Transform` as shown in the answer to this question [Dart create and transform an SVG path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815390/dart-create-and-transform-an-svg-path)

```dart
Matrix m = new svg.SvgSvgElement().createSvgMatrix();
Matrix m2 = m.translate(50, 50);
Transform tr = ellipse.transform.baseVal.createSvgTransformFromMatrix(m2);
ellipse.transform.baseVal.appendItem(tr);
```

You can set the color with

```dart
ellipse.style.setProperty('fill', '#07f');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I'll test it as soon as I can. Regarding the style, I knew that, I was just wondering what is the use of style.setColor and the other methods. The lack of documentation is killing my enthusiasm :(

Comment: AFAIK color is a default `foreground color` style property applicable for normal HTML elements. SVG-Elements inherit such properties even when it's not applicable to them.