# The right way to set SvgElement styles and transforms

Tags: svg, dart

There are multiple ways to set a svg element's styles and transforms. For example, you can set the style through:

```
element.style.setProperty('opacity', '0.5');
element.style.setProperty('stroke', 'red');
```

or

```
element.style
..opacity = '0.5'
..stroke = 'red';
```

You can set transforms by:

```
element.setAttribute('transform', 'translate($x, $y)');
```

or methods mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873601/dart-svg-translate-an-object)

```
element.transform.baseVal.first.setTranslate(x, y);
or
element.transform.baseVal.appendItem(transform);
```

My question is, in terms of performance, which method is better to use or they are same?

Comment: I guess you will need to benchmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your methods of transforms did not show `matrix transforms`;)...

I can speak about my opinions with transforms. Basically, if you are going to apply more than one transform to an element, it is more efficient to use `matrices`, rather than extending the transform values as long strings. I tested this about 5 years ago, with my own benchmark(I can't find it in my files), and recall a minor improvement. In any case, matrices are easy to work with, for extended transforms.