# Dart SVG Matrix Transformation

Tags: svg, dart

I am trying to create a class (in Dart) that makes a SVG group transformable through a matrix. I've tried to use the 'setAttribute' route,  and it works for a single SvgElement:

Transform Class:

```
  String _x;
  Element _transformElement;

  void setX(int value)
  {
    _x = value.toString();
    _transformElement.setAttribute('x', _x);
  }
```

Dart file:

```
Transform test = new Transform('testObject');

void main()
{
  test.setX(25);
}
```

However, I would like to be able to make all of the setters run through a single matrix. Here is my code:

Transform Class:

```
Matrix _matrix;

void setX(int value) => setTransform(x: value);

void setTransform({int scaleX: null, int skewX: null, int skewY: null, int scaleY: null, int x: null, int y: null})
{
  _matrix.a = scaleX;
  _matrix.b = skewX;
  _matrix.c = skewY;
  _matrix.d = scaleY;
  _matrix.e = x;
  _matrix.f = y;

  _transformElement.setAttribute('width', _matrix.a.toString());
  _transformElement.setAttribute('height', _matrix.d.toString());
  _transformElement.setAttribute('x', _matrix.e.toString());
  _transformElement.setAttribute('y', _matrix.f.toString());
}
```

My error is that the _matrix is null. Also, I would like this to work for a group of SVG objects and not just one SVGElement

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more what you try to accomplish. A concrete (minimal) SVG example and what transformation you want to do on them. Did you have a look at these questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791926, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873601?

Comment: You don't assign a value to `matrix` this is why it is `null`.  
See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873601 for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [createSVGMatrix](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__createSVGMatrix) to get a matrix that you can manipulate

If you're working in an SVG document then you could call it this way.

```
var matrix = document.documentElement.createSVGMatrix();
```

If you have a html document with inline SVG in it then you'll need to get the root SVG element and call createMatrix() on that.